# How can I listen to xhr response using chrome-extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I want execute a function when some a chrome window gets a XHR response.

I don't know what exactly this request is like, because of a codified param of this request, for example: `api.xxx.com/rest?random=123`

So I don't think I could use

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(function callback)
```

or

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function callback)
```

which both need specify the request details.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The listeners for those events do not need you to specify the request details. On the contrary, they provide you with those details, when the get called.

Since you want to listen for any XHR request, you can define the special `<all_urls>` match pattern (or `*://*/*` to limit them to just `http/https` requests).

E.g.:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function (details) {
  // Process the XHR response metadata. The request body is not available
  ...
}, {urls: ['<all_urls>']});
```

---

Don't forget to declare the appropriate permissions, according to your requirements.
E.g.:

```
// In `manifest.json`:
...
"permissions": {
  ...
  "webRequest",
  "<all_urls>"   // <-- add this to listen for XHR from all pages
]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I can now execute my function when response returns. But I still can't get response body which is expected as a json. It seems that I need to use url in the details open a get request>

Comment: I don't think the `webRequest` API gives access to the response body. You can access the response headers and status code, but that's it.

Comment: Having the same problem, I can can confirm you have no access to the response body. Firefox introduced "StreamFilters", but unfortunately Chrome did not implememt this feature.

Comment: This does not give access to responseBody